# Confusing error: Optionality of map's variable changes it from single object to array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have:

```
private var wrappedObjects: [WrapperClass]?

var objects: [SomeClass]?
{
    didSet
    {
        self.wrappedObjects = objects.map{ WrapperClass($0) }
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
`Cannot convert value of type '[SomeClass]' to expected argument type 'SomeClass'`
```

However when I just change one line to:

```
var objects: [SomeClass] = []
```

the error is gone.

Why does the optionality of `objects` makes `map` think `$0` is either a single `SomeClass` or an array `[SomeClass]` respectively?

Comment: By the way, do you really want two separate stored properties (i.e. two renditions of the same array), one for `objects` and yet another for `wrappedObjects`? Often you might implement `objects` as a computed property that updates `wrappedObjects`. But here you have two copies of the array. If that's what you need, that's fine, but it's a tad unusual..

Comment: @Rob In reality `WrapperClass` is a protocol with two implementations. I have two public `var`'s (one for each implementation that both map to the wrapped array) of which only one will be set. Internally I then only use what's now called `wrappedObjects`. So good point. I'd need a kind of set-only property (two of those). What would you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that there are two `map(_:)` functions. [One for sequences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905795-map):

```
public protocol Sequence {
    // ...

    /// Returns an array containing the results of mapping the given closure
    /// over the sequence's elements.
    /// 
    /// - Parameter transform: A mapping closure. `transform` accepts an
    ///   element of this sequence as its parameter and returns a transformed
    ///   value of the same or of a different type.
    /// - Returns: An array containing the transformed elements of this
    ///   sequence.
    func map<T>(_ transform: (Iterator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]

    // ...
}
```

and [one for optionals](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map):

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    // ...

    /// Evaluates the given closure when this `Optional` instance is not `nil`,
    /// passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.
    ///
    /// - Parameter transform: A closure that takes the unwrapped value
    ///   of the instance.
    /// - Returns: The result of the given closure. If this instance is `nil`,
    ///   returns `nil`.
    public func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?

    // ...
}
```

Therefore when you call `map` on a `[SomeClass]?`, the second `map` function will be used, where the transformation function parameter will be of type `[SomeClass]`, as `map` will unwrap it for you, and apply a given transformation to it.

However, when you call `map` on a `[SomeClass]`, the first `map` function will be used, where the elements will be iterated through – applying the transformation function to each of them. Therefore the parameter type of the transformation function will be `SomeClass`.

One amusing solution therefore would be to use `map` twice – once to unwrap, once to apply a transform to the elements:

```
self.wrappedObjects = objects.map{ $0.map{ WrapperClass($0) } }
```

However, this is absolutely ridiculous, you should definitely use optional chaining [as Rob suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38914903/2976878).

Comment: Can you share a meaningful example for using the 2nd `map`?

Comment: @Honey How about https://stackoverflow.com/q/40141531/2976878 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/39425457/2976878 for examples? It's quite a useful tool to have when working with optionals.

Comment: Thank you so much for links. Useful! About 2nd link: Knowing that `flatMap` removes `nil` values from collections, I thought `flatMap` would be something that would unwrap. Anyhow, if I understand this correct, instead of the trouble of doing `var name: String? = "kkk";
var userName : String?;
if let x = name{
 userName = "@ \(x)";
}` you can just do `let ausername = aname.map { "@" + $0 }` which is more Swifty?

Comment: @Honey `Optional` does also have a `flatMap` method; it allows the transform itself to return `nil`, squashing the resulting value down from two levels of optionality (if it were applied with `map`) down to one. And yes, you understand it quite correctly :)

Comment: @Hamish I don't understand your English. "(if it were applied with map)" then what?! Because prior to that, in your sentence you're talking about `flatMap`...

Answer (score 4):

You want employ some optional chaining, e.g.:

```
self.wrappedObjects = objects?.map { WrapperClass($0) }
```

That will return `nil` if `objects` was `nil`, or will `map` through the items in `objects` if not `nil`.