# Concatenate literal with Optional String

Tags: swift

Whats the proper way to implement this ? preferably in one line.

```
var name: String?
...
let username = "@" + name
```

Note: `username` must be `String?` I don't want to unwrap `name` for concatenation.

Edit: if `name` is `nil`, `username` should also be `nil`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `map` method of `Optional`:

```
let username = name.map { "@" + $0 }
```

If `name` is `nil` then the closure is not executed and the result is `nil`. Otherwise the closure is evaluated  with `$0` set to the unwrapped name.

Comment: This is great ! short and elegant.

Comment: didn't you mean to use `flatmap`? I mean isn't `flatmap` the one function that ignores `nil`s?

Comment: @Honey: flatmap can be used if the return type of the closure is an optional, it should not be necessary here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
let username = name.flatMap { "@\($0)" }
```

Comment: This also works great, Martin R's solution was more elegant. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### EDITED based on updated requirements:

You can do it a couple of ways. Here's one:

```
var name: String?
var username: String?

if let name = name {
  username = "@" + name
}
```

Comment: I saw that in the comments after I posted my answer. I've updated my answer to give the desired results.

Comment: I tend to prefer clarity over brevity. Short and confusing isn't better than longer and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest and more readable option is using `if let` but you could also define a method to `prepend` a `String`, opposed to `String.append` and then use optional chaining:

```
extension String {
    func prepending(prefix: String) -> String {
        return prefix + self
    }
}

var name: String?
let username = name?.prepending("@")
```

Comment: @navit The amount of code is one of the worst code metrics.