# Propagate an optional through a function (or Init) in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

does anyone have a (better) way to do this?

Lets say I have a optional Float

```
let f: Float? = 2
```

Now I want to cast it to a Double

```
let d = Double(f) //fail
```

This will obviously fail but is there a way to chain the optional through the function like you can with calculated variables?  What I am doing now is this:

```
extension Float {
    var double: Double { return Double(self) }
}
let d: Double? = f?.double
```

But I really do not like putting a cast as a calculated variable.

Another option I have considered using is this:

```
public func optionalize<A,B>(_ λ : @escaping (A) -> B) -> (A?) -> B? {
    return { (a) in
        guard let a = a else { return nil }
        return λ(a)
    }
}
let d: Double? = optionalize(Double.init)(f)
```

I realize I can guard the value of 'f' to unwrap it.  However in many cases the optional value will be the parameter for a function that returns an optional.  This leads to intermediate values in the guard.  As seen in this example:

```
func foo(_ a: String?) throws -> Float {
    guard 
        let a = a,
        let intermediate = Float(a)
    else { throw.something }
    return intermediate
}
```

Here it is possible for the cast from String to Float to fail also.
At least with a calculated variable this foo function is a bit cleaner

```
extension String {
    var float: Float? { return Float(self) }
}

func foo(_ a: String?) throws -> Float {
    guard 
        let a = a?.float
    else { throw.something }
    return a
}
```

I do not want to rewrite optional versions of frequent inits.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425457/concatenate-literal-with-optional-string.

Comment: I recommend you to check [Runes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Runes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `Optional`'s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) method, which will return the wrapped value with a given transform applied if it's non-nil, else it will return `nil`.

```
let f : Float? = 2

// If f is non-nil, return the result from the wrapped value passed to Double(_:),
// else return nil.
let d = f.map { Double($0) }
```

Which, as you point out in the comments below, can also be said as:

```
let d = f.map(Double.init)
```

This is because `map(_:)` expects a transformation function of type `(Float) -> Double` in this case, and [`Double`'s float initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/double/1540132-init) *is* such a function.

If the transform also returns an optional (such as when converting an `String` to a `Int`), you can use [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap), which simply propagates a `nil` transform result back to the caller:

```
let s : String? = "3"

// If s is non-nil, return the result from the wrapped value being passed to the Int(_:)
// initialiser. If s is nil, or Int($0) returns nil, return nil.
let i = s.flatMap { Int($0) }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I do not know why I did not think of this!  Only change would be f.map(Double.init) just as a stylistic thing ;)

Comment: @MrFlynn Sure, thanks for mentioning that – I've edited my answer to include it. Although note that sometimes the compiler will want you to disambiguate the initialiser by saying `map(XYZ.init(_:))` – and at that point I definitely think the closure syntax is cleaner :)