# Can I check if an optional is nil by using it as an argument?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a class with an optional zoomURL property `let zoomURL : String?`

I've been playing around with optional chaining to try and shorten the amount of nil checks I make. I know for the below I could easily check if the `let zoomURLString = meeting.zoomURL` but is it possible to skip this step and use it immediately as an argument within a function and check if this function is nil?

For example: (This fails)

```
if let parsedZoomURL = URL(string: meeting.zoomURL?){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'd consider also to *shorten the amount of* optional types. ;-)

Comment: How about `if let parsedZoomURL = URL(string: meeting.zoomURL ?? "")` ?

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Propagate an optional through a function (or Init) in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40141531/2976878)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the

```
public func flatMap<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
```

method of `Optional`:

```
if let parsedZoomURL = zoomURL.flatMap( { URL(string: $0) }) {
    //do stuff
}
```

or shorter (as someone noticed in a now deleted comment):

```
if let parsedZoomURL = zoomURL.flatMap(URL.init) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The optional binding succeeds only if `zoomURL` is not `nil`
*and* the closure (which is then called with the unwrapped value
of `zoomURL`) does not return `nil`.

Comment: Interesting, always forgetting about map/flatMap methods built in Optional. Thanks.

Comment: For `zoomURL.flatMap(URL.init)` how does the URL initialiser know to use the zoomURL property without `$0`? I like using `map` `filter` and `reduce` but I fear the `$0` harms readability for devs who haven't used these functions before.

Comment: @Deco: `x.flatMap(...)` takes a *function* as parameter and calls that function with the argument `x`. That function can be a literal closure like `{ URL(string: $0) }`, where `$0` is the shorthand for the first parameter.  That function can also be `URL.init` (and if there is more than one init method taking a single argument then the compiler figures out which one matches the argument type).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to you can create an `init` extension for `URL` that supports `nil` values to be passed. Returns `nil` if the string is `nil`.

```
extension URL {

    init?(string: String?) {

        guard let url = string else { return nil }

        self.init(string: url)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let url = URL(string: meeting.zoomUrl) {

    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift will not chain `nil`s on method calls, but it will let you use the same chaining syntax with an extension property:

```
extension String {
    var asURL : URL {
        get {
            return URL(string: self)!
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use chaining as usual:

```
if let parsedZoomURL = meeting.zoomURL?.asURL {
    //do stuff
}
```