# Error while mapping an array: Value of type '[X]' has no member "a"

Tags: swift

I am trying to get an array of string from a specific property in an array of custom objects

```
    let contracts : [Contract]? = Contract.all()
    let contractCategoryNames = contracts.map {$0.categoryName}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
Value of type '[Contract]' has no member 'categoryName'
```

What am I doing wrong here? My understanding is that `$0` there is actually the element of the `[Contract]` array.

Comment: `contracts` is an *optional* array, you need to unwrap it.

Comment: `Optional<T>` or (`T?`) also have `map` and `flatMap` and without putting `?` before you `.map` you're calling `map` over `Optional`, instead of `Array`.

Comment: Basically a dupe of [Confusing error: Optionality of map's variable changes it from single object to array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38914811/2976878)