# Why is mapping over Optional Array different from non-optionalArray

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type, enumeration

```
let optionalArray : [Int]? = [1,2,3]

optionalArray.map({
    print("beforeEach element");
    print($0);
})


let nonOptionalArray  = [1,2,3]

nonOptionalArray.map({
    print("beforeEach element");
    print($0);
})
```

The output:

> beforeEach element
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   beforeEach element
>   1
>   beforeEach element
>   2
>   beforeEach element
>   3

I was using an OptionalArray and the `$0` was **returning the entire array**. Why? Am I not looping over it?!

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/38914811/2976878

Comment: @Hamish so long story short this would *just* unwrap the array/optional and then apply to the closure to the 'array', not to 'each element'?

Comment: Quite correct @Honey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the map on an `Optional<[Int]>`, which also supports map.

You want `optionalArray?.map` to run the map on the array the optional might be wrapping.

Comment: I guess the major source of confusion is that normally the compiler will throw an error that you need to unwrap this using `?` or `!` to be able call this function on it. But here it didn't warn or throw an error!. For this case, you can use the function with the **same** name for both its *unwrapped* and *wrapped* value. Because they are 2 functions with the same name...

Comment: It's because map (and flatMap) are a general concept that work for a lot of types and try to have the same meaning.